# source information from 3 files and generate output according to specific condition

Tags: extract, filehandle

file 1  reference num
 
case1   255
case2   258
case3   555

file 2
test A::case1
result: 111
test B::case1
result: 101

file 3 (file name: box1_box2_255_content.txt)
    ppppppp
    1234567
    xxxxxxx # 5000
 
cap xMxxxxx # 5001
    xxxxxxx # 5002
cap xMxxxxx # 5003
    xxxxxxx # 5004
cap xMxxxxx # 5005
    xxxxxxx # 5006
cap xxxxMxx # 5007
    xxxxxxx # 5008
cap xxxxMxx # 5009
    xxxxxxx # 5010
cap xxxxMxx # 5011

match 'case1' in file2 to file1 and get related reference num, then use reference num to find file3 name. Extract number, boxn, pn if found 'cap' & 'M'. Extract 1st result (for box1) & 2nd result (for box2) from file2. Generate output file with all extracted info. Note that 5007 = 5001 + 3*2, 3 is result bit.

Output
box1_box2_255_content 5001 p2 1 1 1
box1_box2_255_content 5007 p5 1 0 1

Comment: How will be the coding looks like if such output is wanted?

Comment: what operating system? do you prefer any specific programming language?

Comment: prefer perl language